# How can I select a subset of values from an array using the values from another array as keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my array of `$keys`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

And my `$values`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Orange
    [2] => Yellow
    [3] => Green
    [4] => Blue
)
```

I want to create a new array of some of the values in `$values` using the values in `$keys` as keys:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Orange
    [3] => Green
    [4] => Blue
)
```

Obviously I can `foreach` to get the values I want, but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something in the plethora of PHP array functions.

I've Googled the question, and the answer comes back as using `array_combine`, which won't achieve the desired output.

Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: Might look at the second answer of the linked one in case there are duplicate values in the `$keys` array.

Comment: Thank you. I'm ashamed to have duplicated a question :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flip the `$keys` array to make the values keys and then use [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$result = array_intersect_key($values, array_flip($keys));
```

Returns the values from `$values` that have the same keys as the flipped `$keys`.

Comment: Indeed, I don't understand why the OP does not want to use `foreach`?

Comment: @sємsєм: I don't have a problem with `foreach`, but if there's a built-in function to achieve the same goal, it's likely to be quicker, isn't it?